# URL conflict with a 'Single Page Layout'

Tags: theme-development

I'm in the technical planning stages of a project which i intend to implement a 'Single Page Layout' on.

I've setup the pages 'people', 'clients', 'contact', 'case studies' etc and taken the content into my Front Page template using the get_page() function, feeding it the page IDs. This works OK.

I'm intending to have the top navigation menu items, when selected, navigate down the page to there respective section and update the url accordingly.

e.g - *Select on 'people' (scrolls down page to 'people' section),  url updates to example.com/people*

however, the url is in conflict, since the 'people' content is setup as a page. And the end-user will be taken away from the front page.

Is there best practice for getting around this?

Thanks in advance,
Cam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle that with a hash (the way javascript does by default) and have the url become example.com#people, or any other delimiter really. It should be as simple as changing the character you're parsing the url for.

UPDATE: Example code as per comments

```
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'Your Label',
    'labels'              => $labels,  //define this elsewhere
    'public'              => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true, //change this if needed
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'menu_position'       => 20,
    'supports'            => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'author',
        'custom-fields',
        'revisions'
    ),
    'taxonomies'          => array(
        'category'
    ),
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true
);
register_post_type( 'single-pages', $args );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type for documentation, you'll probably needa drop/tweak some of those args to meet your spec on the project and you definitely need to setup the labels for usability if it's a client's site, but that should get you going. This code is untested (I wrote it directly into the textarea, so forgive any typos).

Comment: it would be ideal not the have the example.com/people url created at all when the page is published for SEO reasons also.. i wouldnt want people navigating to any page outside the front page thro search results

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question then. Are you dynamically loading the content from the people page and then scrolling to it, or is there a people section on the homepage that you are taking the user to?

Comment: sorry, i've created the page 'people', and published it. The content from that page is then taken into my frontpage template using the get_page(). this has been repeated for 5 different pages. so all site content is on my 'Single Page Layout'.  if that makes sense?

Comment: 'Single Page Layout' make be the wrong term.... 'One Page Layout'

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you considered registering a non-publiclly viewable custom-post-type to do this? I'll edit my answer shortly with example code.

Comment: Code added, you need to be careful with how you're doing this though, or search engines will not see a significant portion of your site (depending on how it loads and how it falls back).